# How do I use WPF SystemCommands.CloseWindow from XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to use WPF commands for a simple user interface. Most of my command bindings are fine, but I can't work out how to use ones in the SystemCommands class. In my XAML I have:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" CanExecute="NewCommandCanExecute" Executed="NewCommandExecuted"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" CanExecute="OpenCommandCanExecute" Executed="OpenCommandExecuted"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" CanExecute="SaveCommandCanExecute" Executed="SaveCommandExecuted"/>
    <CommandBinding Command="SystemCommands.CloseWindow" CanExecute="CloseWindowCanExecute" Executed="CloseWindowExecuted"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The ones in ApplicationCommands are working exactly as expected, but the `SystemCommand.CloseWIndow` gives the error 'The member "CloseWindow" is not recognized or is not accessible.'

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you use auto-complete? The IDE will make suggestions and show you the accessible members, which would have revealed the the wrong member name to you. The NET API browser is also a good place to lookup members: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcommands.closewindowcommand?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_SystemCommands_CloseWindowCommand.

Comment: If you reference the static member using the `x:Static` extension you get auto-complete support: `<CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" />`. You should use  x:Static for all static members and enum values in order to enable auto-complete (opposed to using strings).

Comment: Useful tip - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RoutedCommand` property is called CloseWindow**Command**:

```
<CommandBinding Command="SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand" .../>
```